# Where to put the JSON file in the Angular Project?

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to open the JSON file I created. The source code that is reading the JSON file is in node_modules directory. I tried putting the JSON file in a common directory (same level as src) but the following error keeps on showing: The requested resource is not found in this server.

TS file reading the JSON file:

```
openJSONFile() {
    let xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            let jsonObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText)
            console.log(jsonObj);
        }
    }

    xmlHttp.open("GET", "../../../../../../../../../common/branch_code_branch_name.json", true);
    xmlHttp.send();
}
```

Location of branch_code_branch_name.json:
[image]

Comment: put it in the `assess` folder and access it in the service and also i recommend you  use `httpCientModule` to read it

Comment: `assets` to be precise.

Comment: @JoelJoseph As @mbojko says, it should be `assets`.

Comment: @cmprogram sorry it was a typo , i ment to say `assets`

Comment: @JoelJoseph You can edit comments.

Comment: @cmprogram  I past 5 minutes, Since it's a comment i can't edit it now

Answer (score 1):

`Assets` folder is created for such data in Angular project.

> [assets](https://angular.io/guide/file-structure) - Contains image and other asset files to be copied as-is when you build your application.

All the static data including your images/Css files/JSON/ or JS files you can include in this folder.

Answer (score 1):

Place your JSON file inside the folder `Assets` that's been created for you when you started a new project with Angular.

Ideally, place additionally directories here to make it easier in the future, i.e. Create some directories like, `css`, `scss`, `js`, `images`, `json`, or even `mock-data`

Then, place your JSON file in the appropriately labelled, `json` directory.

When referencing this file, ensure the number of "../" that you place, represent the accurate number of directories UP you want to access.
For example, if I have a ts file, and it's found in:

`app->users->services->user-service`

And it needs to reference a json file in the aforementioned location, then I would use:

`'../../../assets/json/nameofmyjsonfile.json'`

If my ts file was TWO more levels deep, it would look like this:

`'../../../../../assets/json/nameofmyjsonfile.json'`

Additionally, you can look into "relative" referencing, to avoid many `'../'`

Comment: I keep getting: Http failure response for http://127.0.0.1:4200/assets/common/branch_code_branch_name.json: 404 Not Found

Comment: Just a reminder that your common file that you mention would have to be in the assets folder. Which is located, inside of src/app/assets. I think potentially you're trying to go to many levels up, or not enough. Your IDE should help you out with this, which one are you using?